# Permission denied for accessing file through restful api

Tags: rest, tomcat, permissions, filesystems, streaming

In my web application, I implemented a method to download file in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/ristore/foundation/xml/{filename}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/xml")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadXMLFile(@PathVariable String filename) throws IOException {
    FileSystemResource xmlFile = new FileSystemResource("/rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/prod/foundation/xml/" + filename + ".xml");
    byte [] content = new byte[(int)xmlFile.contentLength()];
    IOUtils.read(xmlFile.getInputStream(), content);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
        .contentLength(xmlFile.contentLength())
        .body(content);
}
```

I hardcoded the path to the files in the method. It is the path to the directory where all the files live on the server where Tomcat instance is running.

I deployed the war on the tomcat server. The web app is owned by the user `risdev`. [image]

However when I try to retrieve the file I got 500. In catalina.out, it shows the error as follows:

```
[/ristore/foundation/xml/TRF174146_09092016230414] due to exception [/rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/prod/foundation/xml/TRF174146_09092016230414.xml (Permission denied)]
```

The admin of the server grant `risdev` access to the folder. When I log in the server as `risdev`, I can read that exact file without any problem.[image]

So why don't I have permission to read it through api? Who is user that is actually getting the file?

**EDIT:**
I found a tomcat process that is associated with the folder where my war is deployed. It is indeed run by risdev who is supposed to have permission to the files.

**EDIT #2**
Just confirmed with the admin who installed tomcat on this server. He indeed used `risdev` to install tomcat instance and run `startup.sh` after installation. So tomcat is owned and run by `risdev` for sure. On the same server, `risdev` definitely has read permission to access files in that folder as confirmed by command line (ls and less). It is just that permission is denied while access the file through tomcat.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following conditions:

1. Tomcat must be started with risdev user in order access to this folder.
2. The folder "/rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/prod/foundation/xml/" and all files inside it must have risdev owner (or read/write permission by others or corresponding group).

For reference you can check the owner of running processes with following command:

```
ps -ef
```

and narrow the result using grep. Example:

```
ps -ef |grep java
```

How to change owner on folder and all files inside it:

```
chown -R rizdev /rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/prod/foundation/xml/
```

Comment: I attached a screen shot of the tomcat process, does that mean tomcat is being run by `risdev`?

Comment: Yes. It seems the tomcat instance runs with the correct user. Let me check what else could be wrong.

Comment: I read again carefully and I can not see you have ensured that the file you are downloading has rizdev owner. I have updated the answer.

Comment: We can't make risdev the owner of that directory. However, as shown in my second attached screenshot, risdev has the read permission to that directory.

Comment: I'm seeing rwxr-xr-x. This means "others" have only execute access, but not read access. Please check risdev user and the owner of directory are in the same group. You need to make permisisons rwxr-xr-xr or to change the group.

Comment: The permission of that file (/rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/prod/foundation/xml/TRF174146_09092016230414.xml) is actually 770 and it belongs to the group `moonshot`. Instead of adding `risdev` to the group, the admin decided to created a read-only group for `moonshot` called `moonshot-ro` which only has read permission to that folder. Maybe tomcat does not recognize the read-only setup on the OS level?

Comment: So you need to assign "moonshot-ro" group to rizdev. In that case tomcat will be started with "moonshot-ro" and will be able to access group permissions of the folder.

Comment: After troubleshooting with our admin, it turned out `moonshot-ro` group was created recently while the tomcat instance for this particular app was started back in June. That's why it is not aware of the new permission change. After restarting tomcat, it works.